# VB .NET Radio Button Checked Property Not Showing As True Properly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radio-button, form-control

I have a page where I am checking the value of several groups of radio buttons.  For each group, if the radio button is selected that is the property I need to save to later store in my db.  As the code stands right now, the radio button Checked property is being set to "true" properly, however, when I read it back from the page it comes back as "false" even though I can see that it is in fact selected on the screen.

Here are the code blocks:

Markup:

```
<form action="#">
    <div class="card-content center-align">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                <asp:RadioButton CssClass="with-gap" ID="rdoArabic1" runat="server" GroupName="ethnicity" />
                <label>Arabic, Middle Easterner</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                <asp:RadioButton CssClass="with-gap" ID="rdoAsian1" runat="server" GroupName="ethnicity" />
                <label>Asian, Pacific Islander, Indian</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                <asp:RadioButton CssClass="with-gap" ID="rdoBlack1" runat="server" GroupName="ethnicity" />
                <label>African American or Black</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content center-align">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                <asp:RadioButton CssClass="with-gap" ID="rdoWhite1" runat="server" GroupName="ethnicity" />
                <label>White, Anglo, European American</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                <asp:RadioButton CssClass="with-gap" ID="rdoHispanic1" runat="server" GroupName="ethnicity" />
                <label>Hispanic, Latino</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                <asp:RadioButton CssClass="with-gap" ID="rdoOther1" runat="server" GroupName="ethnicity" />
                <label>Other</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

VB Code:

```
If rdoArabic1.Checked = True Then
    ethnicity = "1"
ElseIf rdoAsian1.Checked = True Then
    ethnicity = "2"
ElseIf rdoBlack1.Checked = True Then
    ethnicity = "3"
ElseIf rdoWhite1.Checked = True Then
    ethnicity = "4"
ElseIf rdoHispanic1.Checked = True Then
    ethnicity = "5"
ElseIf rdoOther1.Checked = True Then
    ethnicity = "6"
End If
```

Anyhow, I've been banging my head against this wall for a while now and I can't seem to see what I'm missing that's causing this to reset.  I've stepped through the code, and the Checked property IS being set to True when the page loads and the info from the database is processed, it's just not reading it back from the form properly for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - apparently the controls didn't like being inside the form tags. Removed all of my form tags and now it's working like a charm. Not sure if that will help anyone ever but I figured I'd follow up just in case.